# Is it possible to start an interactive REPL session (R, python, etc) on a condor system?

Tags: python, r, interactive, read-eval-print-loop, condor

I want to request, say, 32 CPUs on a condor cluster. Normally, I can submit a job saying to run a program for example with:

`my_R_script.sh`:

```
Rscript my_R_program.R
```

`my_condor_job`:

```
Universe     = vanilla
getenv       = True
Executable   = my_R_script.sh
Output       = condor.out
Error        = condor.error
Log          = condor.log
request_cpus = 32

queue
```

`condor_submit my_condor_job`

but this operates under the presumption that `my_R_program.R` already has all the commands I want to enter. Instead, I'd like to start for example an interactive R session and utilize the 32 CPUs interactively. Is this possible on condor?

Answer (score 0):

`condor_submit -i my_condor_job` will start an interactive session on the machine that you are matched with. Be aware that the file listed as the executable in your submit file will not be transferred (or automatically run) in this mode.